# Show message with custom "content" when visitors try to add product to wishlist

Tags: price, wishlist, out-of-stock, stock-status

Visitors are allowed to add product to wishlist and I would like to display a message content something like "you need to be signed in, in order to add product to your wishlist".

By default Magento doesn't display any messages and I think this can be confusing to some visitors.

Any idea how this can be done.

Also, same goes with the advice messages for "price change" and "back in stock".

thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not too clear what you are asking. How should this message be displayed? And where

Comment: for example if you visit the following link:

http://demo.icebergcommerce.com/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html

and than try to add this product to wish list, you will be forward to:

http://demo.icebergcommerce.com/customer/account/login/

There i would like to add a message from above question/post. 

thanks